# Firebase hosting rewrites issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a react app hosted on firebase hosting. I want to call from the app function but have an issue.
I followed [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)
but still getting errors. For testing, I'm using a firebase emulator.

Express function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as express from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {corsOptions} from "../middleware/cors";

const keys = require("../../jwt.keys.json");
admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(keys)});
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const app = express();
const API_PREFIX = "api";
app.use((req, _res, next) => {
if (req.url.indexOf(`/${API_PREFIX}/`) === 0) {
  req.url = req.url.substring(API_PREFIX.length + 1);
}
next();
});
app.post("/", cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
try {
  const driver = req.body as any;
  const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
    email: driver.email,
    emailVerified: true,
    password: driver.password,
    displayName: `${driver.firstName} ${driver.lastName}`,
    disabled: false,
  });
  delete driver.password;
  delete driver.confirmPassword;
  delete driver.id;
  await firestore.collection("users").doc(userRecord.uid).create(driver);
  return res.status(200).json({message: `${userRecord.uid}
  has been created`});
} catch (error) {
  return res.status(500).json({error: error.toString()});
}
});
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

firebase.json:

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "webApp/build",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/**",
      "function": "api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Cors file:

```
const whitelist = ["http://localhost:5000", "http://localhost:3000"];

export const corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
};
```

Request url: `http://localhost:5001/api/`
Error message in console:

> Access to fetch at
> 'http://localhost:5001/api' from origin
> 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

Also preflight request returns 404 Not Found

Can someone give a direction on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on what you've posted, `corsOptions` is undefined? You'd expect something like `{origin: true}` or `{origin: ["http://localhost:5000","https://PROJECTID.firebaseapp.com","https://PROJECTID.web.app"]}`

Comment: Also, Firebase Functions can be executed using default credentials using just `admin.initializeApp();`

Comment: @samthecodingman, sorry. I missed that part to show, updated question

Comment: Usually the preflight request returns a valid HTTP status, but since it's actually sending `404`, it looks like the issue is with that. The CORS config is ok, but the issue is with what is being fetched from the server